# Counting minutes of calling in app (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, phone-call

I need some methods for counting banda usage, minutes of calling, number of sms sent, and more (for iOS).

Is there a way to access any of this information?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is any possibility for you to do this. This amounts to spying on the user of your application on his privacy, which surely would be reject by Apple. And they have also not opened any APIs for this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think apple will be happy to have other apps accessing these data. You cannot do it the official SDK